# Logout CSRF Protection

Tags: php, csrf, cms

I am making a CMS and I have a CSRF protection in settings, new article. Should I also put this protection in the logout ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: You should have CSRF protection EVERYWHERE where you do something which requires the permission of the current logged in user and is changing some data.